# jqplot: draw series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I want to draw some data using jqplot and I have a small issue.

The code I use is this ([code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTwU2/4/)):

```
$.jqplot('chart1', [[202],[249],[148]], {
    seriesColors : ['#ff0000', '#0f0', '#00f'],
    seriesDefaults : {
       renderer :$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
       pointLabels : {
           show : true
       },
       tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            barDirection : 'horizontal'
        }
    },
    axes: { 
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, 
            ticks: ["some value", "other series", "third series"],
        },
    },
});
```

The graph has 3 horizontal regions, "some value", "other series" and "third series"
I need that each graph bar to be under corresponding region, and to keep the colors as now (red to "some value", green to "other series" and blue to "third series").

**How do I need to format the data to get this?**

As extra questions:

1. I want few pixels margin between yaxis and corresponding axe labels. How do I set this?
2. The graph has a bg color (fade yellow). How do I eliminate that color and to get as bg whatever color the container has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your data to

```
data = [[[202,1],[248,2],[148,3]]];
```

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/vTwU2/12/).

**PS1 :** You can change width of the bar by setting barWidth = xx; where xx is in pixels (50px in given example).

**PS2 :** For your first extra question, you can add something like this :

```
$("#chart1 .jqplot-grid-canvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-grid-canvas").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-series-shadowCanvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-series-shadowCanvas").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-series-canvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-series-canvas").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-point-label").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-point-label").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-highlight-canvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-highlight-canvas").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-highlighter-tooltip").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-highlighter-tooltip").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-barRenderer-highlight-canvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-barRenderer-highlight-canvas").offset().left+5});
$("#chart1 .jqplot-event-canvas").offset({left:$("#chart1 .jqplot-event-canvas").offset().left+5});
```

I'm pretty sure you can make it a cleaner way but it works (change the `+5` values to whatever you need in order to move the chart block). Please see an updated working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/vTwU2/14/)

Comment: Nice. But, if you look closely, you can see that each bar is not middle centered. DO you know how to center it? (like green bar, aligned with the label text).

Comment: Change your data from data = [[[202,1]],[[249,2]],[[148,3]]]; to data = [[[202,1],[248,2],[148,3]]]; (sorry for brackets misplacing).

Comment: Example updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/vTwU2/14/) answering (not a clean way to do it) your first extra question